# Logging of received/transmitted messages in Service Broker

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, service-broker

Is there a way to log (in a file or database table) the messages sent to and/or received from a Service Broker service without altering the activation procedure or message sending code?

I know I can alter the activation procedure to write the received message to a table before (or after) processing it. And I can change the sending stored procedure to do the same but I am looking for something that:

- I won't have to build the infrastructure on my own and code and debug from scratch.
- Has been extensively tested and known to not interfere with normal processing (transparent).
- I can enable or disable at will.

Note: I need to log the actual message content and associated metadata.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No.

You can monitor the [Broker:Conversation Event Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/event-classes/broker-conversation-event-class) via a server trace or as a event notification but will only give you metadata, not the message content.

You can enable [queue retention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-queue-transact-sql) but the retained messages are deleted anyway when the conversation ends and is problematic to turn on/off.

The best option, by far, is to do it from the activated stored procedure itself.